# The form won't edit the database entry, I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing with this

Tags: python, mongodb, forms, flask, arguments

So I'm making a small personal library app using mongoDB, flask and Python where you can input the entries for your books and keep them in a sort of account/login.
The issue is, I can't get the form itself to ping the function to edit things. I know I'm targeting wrong, but I feel like I'm at a point where I need someone to explain like I'm five where I'm going wrong.

So this is the function:

```
@app.route("/profile/<username>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def edit_book(book_id, username):
    if request.method == "POST":
        submit = {
            "category_name": request.form.get("category_name"),
            "title": request.form.get("title"),
            "author": request.form.get("author"),
            "genre": request.form.get("genre"),
            "rating": request.form.get("rating"),
            "release_date": request.form.get("release_date"),
            "publisher": request.form.get("publisher"),
            "page_count": request.form.get("page_count"),
            "isbn": request.form.get("isbn")
        }
        mongo.db.booksread.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(book_id)}, submit)
        mongo.db.bookstoberead.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(book_id)}, submit)
        flash("Book Entry Edited")

    unreadbooks = mongo.db.bookstoberead.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(book_id)})
    books = mongo.db.booksread.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(book_id)})
    categories = mongo.db.reading_list.find().sort("category_name", 1)

    return redirect(url_for("profile", booksread=books, readinglist=categories, bookstoberead=unreadbooks))
```

and this is the post action linked with it:

```
<form class="col s12" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('edit_book', book_id=book_id, username=username) }}">
```

The repos is here([Personal Library App](https://github.com/digimori/PersonalLibraryApp)), and the app with all of the functions is under "app.py", and the page that the form is linked on is "profile.html" under the templates folder.

Live preview is [On Heroku](https://personal-library-mongodb.herokuapp.com/), if that helps to see where things are linked together. You can use the username/password of Tester/Tester1 for access.

I've tried passing different arguments in for the post action, function and the route. I don't know if I'm passing the wrong arguments in or if there are instances I've missed, I'm still very very hazy on arguments as it is.
I've tried to make heads or tails of some documentation, but something just isn't clicking.

Any and every piece of help is absolutely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Flask, you can add variables to your Route that will then be passed to the view function as keyword arguments. In your example, you define a method with two arguments `book_id` and `username`. But in your route, you **only** define the `username` as a variable `@app.route("/profile/<username>", ...)`.

This would lead to a Type error when flask tries to call your method with only the username.

Because you have not posted the error message, I can only assume that something like the following is raised.
`TypeError: edit_book() missing 1 required positional argument: 'book_id'`

The URL generated by the `url_for('edit_book', book_id=book_id, username=username)` method will not raise any errors and build a URL like `profile/exampleuser?book_id=99` with all unknown parameters as query parameters.

As a fix you could simply add the book_id as a second route variable.

```py
@app.route("/profile/<username>/<book_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def edit_book(book_id, username):
```

For additional information, view:

- https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#url-route-registrations
- https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#variable-rules

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try this method but then when I do I get the following error:
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Which leads me to believe it's an issue with the form itself not pinging against the function route properly.

Comment: When you get this error, the url_for either create a wrong URL or you are still on a cached site with the old `/2?book_id=2` URL. Try to debug by looking up the site source code in your browser and compare the rendered post URL with the `/profile/username/book_id` that you should have. Also, try to access the site manually by editing the browser URL to fit a valid username and book_id.

Comment: The Error I get on form submission is that the port is closing before the request can send. I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out.
The post action needed to be "book_id=book._id" instead as I'm targeting the ID of the database entry.
The second issue was that on the redirect, I wasn't targeting a session. The records are locked behind a logged in profile, so I needed to target the logged in session in order for it to go anywhere.
All fixed.